# Мониторинг приложений в Google Play Market

Tags: google-play, playmarket

Кто может посоветовать способ мониторить наличие своего приложения в Play Market'e?

Не всегда есть доступ к консоли разработчика и будет бот, который будет чекать приложение - живое или уже нет.

Если приложение заблокируют или удалят, всегда будет страница выглядеть как на скрине ниже?
[image: скрин]
Если так, тогда это упрощает.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Например, если имя вашего пакета "com.unknown", то ссылка к вашему приложению в маркете будет такой - https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.unknown

Если приложение удалено/заблокировано в Play Market, тогда Url вернет страницу 404.

Банальный пример на C#:

```
try
{
    var client = new WebClient().DownloadString("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.unknown");
    Console.WriteLine("Ok");
}
catch
{
    Console.WriteLine("Bad");
}
```